# Throwing http 500 error and removing htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

This site [www.collegeconn.com](http://www.collegeconn.com) is suddenly throwing this error and to fix the error I have tried every possible changes. I have renamed htaccess file to check if it is the cause but still the same error occurs stating bellow error message

> The collegeconn.com page isn’t working
>
> collegeconn.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR
>   500

Comment: find out where your php error log and possibly your server error log are, and read them.

Comment: It's basically , some code which is currpt or conflicted with something , might can be a condition which is not working properly or it can be anything miss placed in code . Turn on your error reporting , then you will see the proper error and not 500

Comment: thought the error reporting in set off its still the same page am displayed

Comment: @BeetleJuice in the cpanel am looking at errors display section but it has nothing , where can i exactly find it in server

Comment: found this on error log ...cannot serve directory /home/wwwcollegeconn/public_html/: no matching DirectoryIndex

Comment: Is there an `index.html` or `index.php` file in that folder?

Comment: yes it has with type application/x-httpd-php and permission 0644 I guess it doesnot affect it

Comment: here is the another error PHP Deprecated: iconv_set_encoding(): Use of iconv.internal_encoding is deprecated in php

Answer (score 0):

You first try to access simple PHP test file by placing them into root folder. If that file runs well than you need to access your files using File Zilla and try to remove .htaccess file.

In case still you are getting error than you need to contact to your hosting provider.